# Prevent embedding small assets into HTML file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby

By default, Gatsby (properly also related to Webpack) will embed assets that are small enough into the HTML files in base64 encoding. I would like to prevent that from happening.

Is there an option from Gatsby that I can configure? Like something similar to `IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT` from CRA.

Alternatively, if the above is not possible, which Webpack config (it is related to Webpack, right?) should I modify to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Give this a try https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleparserdataurlcondition

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, [`dataUrlCondition`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleparserdataurlcondition) probably is what you are looking for.

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions, loaders, getConfig }) => {
  const config = getConfig();

  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          parser: {
            dataUrlCondition: {
              maxSize: 4 * 1024,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });
};
```

Gatsby ships with his own webpack configuration but you can customize it using [`onCreateWebpackConfig` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#onCreateWebpackConfig) in your `gatsby-node.js`.

Regarding the `parser`, if a module source size is less than `maxSize` then it will be injected into the bundle as a Base64-encoded string, otherwise, the module-file will be emitted into the output directory.

Comment: In theory, `dataUrlCondition.maxSize` should be what I'm looking for, but just copying and pasting your answer will cause the compilation to fail. I currently try and error and see what can I find out